# Cocoa Static Library with ZXing error

Tags: ios, static-libraries, zxing

My project uses some Cocoa static libraries, one of which is a Zxing Project. I am getting a lot of errors while trying to incorporate this project. Weirdly enough, I was able to create a demo with Zxing in a separate project, without any errors. My main project builds and runs ok, as long as I do not include the Cocoa static library for Zxing.

So the question is, how do I include the ZXing static library to my Cocoa project? How do I configure library (e.g. how do I set the Header Search Paths~~).

Thanks.

Some detail about my project

The Structure

EnjoyMobile
  -CustomStaticLibrary.xcodeproj
     -ZXingWidegt.xcodeproj

Header search Paths in my  -CustomStaticLibrary Target
./zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes
./zxing/cpp/core/src

The error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_QRCodeReader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libCustomerLibrary.a(CustomerViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: If you're asking about an error, you should include the text of the error. Also, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You'll get more and better help if you edit the question to focus on a single, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Zxing is kind of a painfull integration, also in the newer versions of Xcode Apple added more error checks. I would suggest you to use cococapods for a better integration or this ObjectiveC wrapper [here](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)

Answer (score 0):

It's not seeing some of the lib classes. Double check the steps in the README, particularly step 2. If it still fails, post the link command that fails.